# Subtle confusion about the definition of µ-measurable function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Roughly speaking, Let (X, A, µ) be a measure space, a real function f on X is called µ-measurable if it is measurable with respect to the σ-algebra Aµ (where Aµ means the set of all µ-measurable sets).

However, when I consulted the notion in the book (Measure Theory, V.I. Bogachev, p108). The author side " we agree to call µ-measurable also µ any function f that is deﬁned and Aµ-measurable on X\Z, where Z is a set of µ-measure zero (that is, f may be undeﬁned or inﬁnite on Z)."

I wonder if we just define such function on X\Z, how could I understand the sense of "Aµ-measurable".

I am not sure if Aµ is still a σ-algebra of X/Z.

Could anyone help me ? many thanks :)